# Why do I need to install a JDK for Java but only an installer for Python?

Tags: java, python, corretto

I just started learning Java, and I am installing the OpenJDK from Amazon Corretto. Why do I need to install this JDK? I am coming from a Python background where I only needed to install the "Python 3" program from the official Python website. Why can't I just install Java? I'm assuming JDK has features that aren't just in Java? What are these extra features?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you install *just* Java, you are installing the **JRE**, or the **Java Runtime Environment**. This guy allows you to run your program inside the *Java Virtual Machine (JVM)*, and is the `java` command.

When you install the **JDK**, or the **Java Development Kit**, you are installing everything that the *JRE* has, but you are also installing the compiler `javac`, which is capable of compiling Java programs. These compiled Java programs can then be run in the *Java Runtime Environment*.

Python, on the other hand, is not a [compiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language) language -- but rather an [interpreted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) one. Therefore it **must** have its equivalent of the `JRE` and `JDK` in one package.

Answer (score 2):

1) The "Python 3" program *is* the Python SDK, broadly speaking

2) Java has a separate installation for development because it is a compiled language. You need a compiler and some supporting files and classes (that is, the JDK) to develop software. But you don't need that to run Java programs, you just need the Java Runtime Environment.

Comment: Since Java 12 there is no `JRE` anymore, only the `JDK`. Or is that info incorrect?

Comment: @second you're not wrong, in that oracle doesn't seem to offer the download anymore but, for example, in debian the jre and jdk are still separate packages.

Comment: @second that's actually since Java 11, but yes.